# Declaring an enum outside a namespace in a project

Tags: c#, architecture, enums

I'm working on a project that follows the 3-Layer architecture and its Data Access layer (DAL) is written by someone else. I checked the code and found that he uses two class libraries and an interface in the Data Access layer (DAL) to connect to the database. The interface is **IDBManager** and class libraries are **DBManagerFactory** and **DBManager**.

In class **DBManagerFactory**, he declares an enum DataProvider like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public enum DataProvider
{
    Oracle, SqlServer, OleDb, Odbc
}

namespace DataAccessLayer
{
    public sealed class DBManagerFactory
    {
        private DBManagerFactory() { }
```

And in the interface **IDBManager**, he uses the enum like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace DataAccessLayer
{
    public interface IDBManager
    {
        DataProvider ProviderType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        string ConnectionString
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

So, my question is that the declaration of enum outside a namespace is a good approach or bad? I think that the enum should be declared inside the namespace and used in another class or other project via the namespace. Please advise the standard approach.

Comment: It is a good practice to package the types into meaningful namespaces so that we will have a clean separation and better idea of those types. But if those types are common across and we don't want type conversions then you may keep them out of namespace.

Comment: @SivaGopal - The only benefit I can see of enum without using a namespace is that we can use it in other classes without adding the  name of the namespace.

Comment: Shory version: yes, it should be inside the namespace; polluting the global namespace is very poor form; it also runs the very real risk of causing conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

For the compiler it doesn't matter too much, as long as there are no name conflicts.

If defined in separate namespaces, two types can have the same name. The "empty" namespace can also be considered a namespace.

Say you have two types, `My.Namespace.DataProvider` and `Your.Namespace.DataProvider`. If you would use both, you have to distinguish one from the other:

```
private My.Namepspace.DataProvider myDataProvider;
private Your.Namepspace.DataProvider yourDataProvider;
```

However if you only want one, you can use a `using`:

```
using My.Namespace;

private DataProvider dataProvider;
```

This makes code more readable. The problem with namespace-less types is that the "empty" namespace is always "included". So consider having `My.Namespace.DataProvider` and the namespace-less `DataProvider`:

```
using My.Namespace;

private DataProvider dataProvider; // <-- unclear which one is used
```

In the above example, the compiler will use `My.Namespace.DataProvider` and as soon as you remove the `using` it will silently switch to the namespace-less type.

It is counter-intuitive, and you generally want to put groups of types in a namespace to "bundle" them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

An interface is defined in order to abstract away from a concrete implementation (so that you can have other modules of code depend only on that abstraction, and not on a specific implementation).

An `enum` could be considered a specific implementation (it has specific values), so immediately the interface depends upon this concrete implementation.  Therefore I would personally prefer for the `enum` be defined in the same namespace as the interface to limit the chance that future maintenance to the code introduces more dependencies (if the `enum` were moved to a different project then if that project has dependencies, they become dependencies of the interface).

Having it in the same namespace would help other developers to consider it a closely coupled dependency of the interface.